# Cognos analytics 11 easy install mode problem about gateway

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

If I  use easy install mode, the setup procedure doesn't have the step which let me set  Gateway install option.
How to install gateway in easy install mode.   [enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPqgg.png

Answer (score 0):

To use install the optional gateway tier, use the Custom Install option (not the Easy Install option).

Here is a document that explains the basics:
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-install-cognos-analytics-111x

Creating and maintaining a Cognos environment is not a trivial task.  You may want to actually read the documentation and/or attend training from an IBM partner.

Comment: I know use the custom install to install gateway. But we need the default ldap which created by Easy install. The Custom install won’t do that for us. I know read document but IBM document is useless in this case , haha. So I am here. Thanks for your answer.